# Prevent click and focus events in Shadow DOM from bubbling up to DOM

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, dom-events

A handful of [Shadow DOM events](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/shadowdom#events) bubble up and can be detected by the DOM. This is creating undesired behavior where "click" events that occur on targets in the Shadow DOM cause listeners attached to the DOM to fire.

Has anyone dealt with this issue before? Is the solution to attach a listener to the Shadow DOM root that catches all these events and prevents them from propagating? Has anyone done this successfully?